# After click reset button, the company text field will be disable and change the background color

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Database
[image]

I - Internal staff
E - External staff

updatestaff.php

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-ui-themes-1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    //---CLICK STAFF TYPE RADIO BUTTON---
    $(".stafftype").click(function() 
    {
        if($(this).val() === 'I')
        {
            $("#staffcompanyname").val('');
            $("#staffcompanyname").attr('disabled', true);
            $("#staffcompanyname").css("background-color", "#CCCCCC");
        }
        else 
        {
            $("#staffcompanyname").attr('disabled', false);
            $("#staffcompanyname").css("background-color", "#D7E5F2");
        }
    }); 

    //---CLICK RESET BUTTON---
    $('#reset').click(function(){
        //[HERE]
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<?php
    //---DB Connection---
    $query = "SELECT *
              FROM staff 
              WHERE staff_ID = 1"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
?>

<body>
<form method="post" action="staff.php">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Staff Type : </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="stafftype" class="stafftype" value="I"
      <?php if($row['staff_type'] == 'I') echo 'checked'; ?> />Internal

      <input type="radio" name="stafftype" class="stafftype" value="E" 
      <?php if($row['staff_type'] == 'E') echo 'checked'; ?> />External
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Company Name : </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="staffcompanyname" id="staffcompanyname" value="<?php echo $row['staff_company']; ?>" 
      maxlength="120" size="40" <?php echo ($row['staff_type'] == 'I') ? 'class="staffcompanydisablefieldcellinput" disabled' : 
      'class="staffcompanyfieldcellinput"'; ?> />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update Staff" ></td>
    <td><input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Reset" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

From above code and above image:
(1) Initial 
    - Staff type radio button will set to Internal (Refer to database with staff_ID = 1)
    - Staff company text field will be disabled (background color : #CCCCCC)

(2) Click External Type
    - Staff type radio button will set to External
    - Staff company text field will be enabled (background color : #D7EF52)

(3) Click Reset Button
    - Staff type radio button will set to Internal
    - Staff company text field will be disabled (background color : #CCCCCC)

However, when I click reset button, the staff company field was not disabled and the text field background color was not set to #CCCCCC.
How should I modify it on [HERE] section in order to get my expected output? Can someone help me?

Comment: Why the mysql tag? [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your radio button doesnt have `ID`, assing `ID='Internal'`

Your **[HERE]** should be

```
$("#Internal").prop("checked", true).triggerHandler('click');
```

OR

```
$("#Internal").trigger('click').prop("checked", true);
```

Comment: Nice... This can only control the internal staff. Another question, how should I control internal staff or external staff using if statement?

Comment: You do the same. Just make sure your external Radio Button has `ID='External'` ... But acording to your requirement you shouldnt need it. Only the reset button wasnt working and this solve that